# What is difference between hmac_sha256, hkdf_sha256 and hmac_sha_512?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, hash, bip32-hd-wallets, bip324-p2p-encryption

In the open source (https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src/crypto) there are these algrithms that as I know connected with gerenation the new keys and master key. So I try to understand what exactly each algorithm does and how they related in Bitcoin Core.

Answer (score 5):

They implement 3 distinct cryptographic schemes:

- `HMAC-SHA256` is a MAC (message authentication code, or a keyed hash function) based on SHA-256. It is used in the RFC6979 nonce generation function for deterministic ECDSA signing.
- `HMAC-SHA512` is a MAC based on SHA-512. It is used in the BIP32 key derivation logic.
- `HKDF-SHA256` is a (symmetric) key derivation function (KDF) based on HMAC-256. It is currently unused, but was added in anticipation of being used in the BIP324 (v2 P2P transport layer) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

HMAC in the name stands for ["**H**ash-based **M**essage **A**uthentication **C**ode"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) and the hmac_sha_512 is used to [generate keys](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0032#Specification:_Key_derivation) in hierarchic-deterministic BIP-0032 wallets, and to [generate a master key](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki#from-mnemonic-to-seed) from the seed phrase (BIP-0039), for example [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/93999a5fbe317852307455b6a42d137cc08a0edc/src/key.cpp#L348).

HKDF in the name stands for ["**H**ash-based **K**ey-**D**erivation **F**unction"](https://su21.cs161.org/proj2/crypto/hkdf.html), and there's a comment in the code which describes it:

> A rfc5869 HKDF implementation with HMAC_SHA256 and fixed key output length of 32 bytes (L=32)

If you look at [rfc5869 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869), it uses some HMAC as a primitive in the key derivation scheme, and in `hkdf_sha256` the `hmac_sha_256` is the primitive i.e. `hmac_sha_256` is used for `hkdf_sha256`. The `hmac_sha_256` is also used in [httprpc.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0de36941eca1bff91420dd878eb097db2b1a596c/src/httprpc.cpp#L113) and [torcontrol.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/6dc3084eec912cf2abfe18d1c05655defaa45e20/src/torcontrol.cpp#L481).

But what is `hkdf_sha256` used for? It [doesn't seem to be used anywhere](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/search?q=CHKDF_HMAC_SHA256_L32).